# Google app engine launcher can not create symlinks on Mac

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine

I have problems passing google app engine [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction) on mac (10.9.4). After I install Google app engine launcher dragging it to "Applications" and running it, I supposed to get a dialog about installing symlinks. However I'm not seeing one. Presumably because of that I can not launch any app (launcher just shows yellow clock icon and my app is not accessible). Running from console gives me:

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py: No such file or directory
```

According to tutorial I supposed to have `/usr/local/google_appengine` folder, but I don't see one.
Also, some answers point me to `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources` where I supposed to find binaries, but what I see there is only unpacked google_appengine.zip file. Clicking "Make symlinks..." menu item in the launcher does not help. Reinstalling, rebooting, using older versions do not help either.

Thank you!

Should I somehow unpack google_appengine.zip somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So this could be related to the python file path. When I run the GAE Application from the command line

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleAppEngineLauncher
```

it shows an error similar to

```
GoogleAppEngineLauncher[19453:559390] Couldn't posix_spawn: error 2
```

which through some round about searches seems to be trying to find python at /usr/bin/python which doesn't exist, or on a Mac, the symlink to the Apple pre-installed python doesn't exist because the user removed it.

```
/usr/bin/python@ -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
```

I removed the existing symlink and ran the following command to create a symlink to my default python

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

and restarted the GAE app. It then prompted me to create symlinks in a dialog box. I was also able to double check that the google_appengine symlinks exist:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine@ -> /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine
```